# Get selected value and submit a form

Tags: forms

I have a form, and I want to get the selected value of `$form['dropdown_third']` and then use the value to create my table.

What should I write in Submit function?

---

```
function find_tryk_filter_test_page($form, &$form_state) {

$options_first = find_tryk_filter_test_first_dropdown_options();
$value_dropdown_first = isset($form_state['values']['dropdown_first']) ? $form_state['values']['dropdown_first'] : key($options_first);

$form['dropdown_first'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'Type',
    '#options' => $options_first,
    '#default_value' => $value_dropdown_first,
    '#ajax' => array(
        'event' => 'change',
        'callback' => 'find_tryk_filter_test_ajax_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'dropdown_second_replace',
    ),
);

$form['dropdown_second'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'Producent',        
    '#prefix' => '<div id="dropdown_second_replace">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#options' => find_tryk_filter_test_second_dropdown_options($value_dropdown_first),
    '#default_value' => isset($form_state['values']['dropdown_second']) ? $form_state['values']['dropdown_second'] : '',
    '#ajax' => array(
        'event' => 'change',
        'callback' => 'find_tryk_filter_test_2_ajax_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'dropdown_third_replace',
    ),
);

if (!empty($value_dropdown_second)){
    $options_second = find_tryk_filter_test_second_dropdown_options($value_dropdown_second);    
    $value_dropdown_second = isset($form_state['values']['dropdown_second']) ? $form_state['values']['dropdown_second'] : key($options_second);
}else{              
    $options_second = array();  
    $value_dropdown_second = isset($form_state['values']['dropdown_second']) ? $form_state['values']['dropdown_second'] : key($options_second);
}

//echo $options_second;
$form['dropdown_third'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'Model',       
    '#prefix' => '<div id="dropdown_third_replace">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',        
    '#options' => find_tryk_filter_test_third_dropdown_options($value_dropdown_second),
    '#default_value' => isset($form_state['values']['dropdown_third']) ? $form_state['values']['dropdown_third'] : '',
);  


$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Find trykluft element'),  
    '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'find_tryk_filter_test_ajax_result_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'result-wrapper',
        'method' => 'replace',
        'effect' => 'fade',
        '#prefix' => '<div id="replace_hotelbook_div">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>'
    ),
);

$header = array('Navn', 'Shoplink', 'Brochure');

$options_third = find_tryk_filter_test_third_dropdown_options($value_dropdown_second);  
$value_dropdown_third = isset($form_state['values']['dropdown_third']) ? $form_state['values']['dropdown_third'] : key(0);
$query = db_query("SELECT node.title, fdfs.field_shoplink_value, fm.uri
    FROM node 
    JOIN field_data_field_model AS fdfm ON
    fdfm.entity_id = node.nid
    JOIN field_data_field_producent AS fdfp ON
    fdfm.entity_id = fdfp.entity_id
    JOIN field_data_field_shoplink AS fdfs
    ON fdfs.entity_id = fdfm.entity_id
    JOIN field_data_field_brochure AS fdfb
    ON fdfb.entity_id = fdfm.entity_id
    JOIN file_managed AS fm ON
    fm.fid = fdfb.field_brochure_fid
    JOIN taxonomy_term_data AS ttd
    ON fdfp.field_producent_tid = ttd.tid
    WHERE fdfm.field_model_value = '".$value_dropdown_third."'");                   

$rows = array();

foreach ($query as $row) {
    $rows[] = array($row->title, $row->field_shoplink_value, $row->uri);                        
}   

$form['webform_results'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#rows' => $rows,
  '#header' => $header
);

return $form;

}
```

Comment: Sorry about the bad layout and the long code.

Comment: No problem. I fixed it for you. Next time take a few minutes and play with the buttons on top of the edit window, you can format code as code block with one click :)

Comment: @MahyarFarshi Just a note, but that db_query is not ideal. You should consider using [`EntityFieldQuery`](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708) instead. Also, currently there's a potential SQL injection vulnerability in that SQL, because you're not using [db query placeholders](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_query/7) at all.

Comment: you have some good points about sql injection. I didnt think about it.

Answer (score 1):

> What should I write in Submit function?

That's up to you, depends what you want to do. It sounds like you're just unsure how to get access to the submitted values. Those reside in `$form_state['values']`, so:

```
$value = $form_state['values']['dropdown_third'];
```

Comment: I tried this one but I got an fatal error :(

Comment: Where have you got the idea that adding that line of code in the submit function is what you're supposed to do? Or are you just adding random bits of code to see what happens?

Comment: I try some random code to see what happens. I really dont know what to write in Submit function :(

Comment: You'll need to get yourself more familiar with the Drupal API first then. We don't have a code writing service here, and teaching you everything you'll need to know to perform an as yet unspecified task is not something we can help you with here. As a hint, I would try breaking your questions down into their smallest possible parts, and then researching how to solve each individual problem separately. You'll find it much easier that way

Comment: You are right, I wil try to break my question in smaller parts. Is it better to do it in here or should I create a question for each of them?

Comment: I can almost guarantee you that once you've broken this down, you won't need to ask any more questions here. What you need to do has been covered hundreds of times on the internet, so you'll easily be able to find tutorials. You'll probably find this site coming up in search results for your individual questions too, with existing answered questions